# Azure storage blobs missing after successful upload

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a strange situation: every once in a while (~100ppm) a blob gets uploaded successfully, but it's missing right after. Following the trail it looks like a single-disk upload acknowledgement and the disk goes down before replication to other disks or locations happens.

The upload code looks like this:

```
try
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
}
catch
{
    await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    throw;
}

if (!await blob.ExistsAsync())
{
    throw new Exception($"Blob uploaded but it doesn't exist: {id}");
}

return id;
```

The logs look like this for a request, first a successful upload followed by an attempt to copy but the blob is missing. There are no delete commands in the middle!

```
1.0;2018-09-08T09:03:58.2752537Z;PutBlob;Success;201;77;77;authenticated;myfiles;myfiles;blob;"https://...";"/...";ee57ce43-...;0;x.x.x.x;2018-03-28;678;63407;258;0;63407;
1.0;2018-09-08T09:07:40.2367140Z;CopyBlob;BlobNotFound;404;66;66;authenticated;myfiles;myfiles;blob;"https://...";"/...";87707e72-...;0;x.x.x.x;2018-03-28;581;0;172;215;0;
```

The storage tier is cold. Is it possible there is actually an upload-acknowledgment after writing the blob to a single disk only?
The losses seem to happen in bursts for multiple uploads within a few seconds.

Another idea: are there any checks for corrupt binary files that happen after the upload? Is it possible the blobs were scrapped by some scanning routines, e.g. photos uploaded from corrupt disks?

Comment: seems like a question for MS support.

Comment: Raised already with MS

Comment: @BenjaminE. Have you tried another azure storage account?  Have you tried to check the blob with [Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) after you upload it?

Comment: @TomSun The account has been migrated about a year ago. The blobs are gone, via portal, storage explorer or programmatically.

Comment: Does it mean that it can't be reproduced now?

Comment: @TomSun As described, this happens in around 100ppm, i.e. 0.01% of all uploads. Unfortunately this is too much for the use case and I need a way to ensure the uploads

Comment: @TomSun It's possible these files are corrupt or someone tries to inject malware, but the thing is the upload passes w/o exceptions. I just need to catch it

Comment: You mean the storage is `cool` ? I know `archive`blob can't be read. You may have some delay before accessing the `cool` blob, not sure

Comment: @Thomas Yes cool storage tier. The SLA for cool is lower than for hot, but Microsoft told me the difference is purely financial, not in lower availability